# passing php encrypted value into javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, parameters

```
<script>   
function dinner(x,y)
{
  alert(x,y);
}
</script>
<?php
$x='o7Y2RUgB3wuKsY4QshuARu/Egj4eQBndOoEj70B3GxQ=';  
$y='12.30'
?>
<a onclick="dinner( <?php echo $x;?>,<?php echo $y;?>);" href="#" style="text-    decoration: none;">click me</a>
```

I am trying to pass encrypted php value(x) into a Javascript function. But I can't get any value in javascript function. I can't understand what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoud add quotes:

```
<a onclick="dinner( '<?php echo $x;?>', '<?php echo $y;?>');" href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code:

```
   <script>   
     function dinner(x,y)
     {
      alert(x + "" + y);
     }
    </script>
    <?php
    $x='o7Y2RUgB3wuKsY4QshuARu/Egj4eQBndOoEj70B3GxQ=';  
    $y='12.30'?>
    <a onclick="dinner( '<?php echo $x;?>','<?php echo $y;?>');" href="#" style="text-    decoration: none;">click me</a>
```

Keep in mind that you are passing strings to the javascript function, so you should place the strings between quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the php script compiles, it sends this

`<a onclick="dinner( o7Y2RUgB3wuKsY4QshuARu/Egj4eQBndOoEj70B3GxQ=,12.30);" href="#" style="text-    decoration: none;">click me</a>`

And then browser tries to use variable named `o7Y2RUgB3wuKsY4QshuARu/Egj4eQBndOoEj70B3GxQ=` and obviously fails.

To fix this issue you have to enclose your `echo`'s with quotes like this

`dinner( '<?php echo $x;?>','<?php echo $y;?>');`

Don't forget to check browser console, there is always useful info.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good way, taking care of all necessary escaping:

```
$clickHandler = sprintf(
  'return dinner(%s, %s)', 
  json_encode($x), 
  json_encode($y)
);

?>
<a href="#" onclick="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($clickHandler, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">click me</a>
```